# How to overlay a line plot on top of a filled.contour?

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I'm trying to put a line plot on top of a filled.contour to achieve a similar effect to the one depicted in Figure 1 [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/evo.12957/full).

```
require("lattice")
require("latticeExtra")

mat = matrix(c(1:9),nrow=3,byrow=TRUE); time = c(1:3); mid = c(1:3)
mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9

line = colMeans(mat)

shades = colorRampPalette(c("red", "green"))
filled.contour(mid,time,t(apply(mat,2,rev)),
                 zlim=c(1,9),nlevels=9,col=shades(9)) 
xyplot(line~time,type="l")
```

The most obvious way to go is using layers, but it hasn't worked for me so far.

```
layer(filled.contour(mid,time,t(apply(mat,2,rev)),
                 zlim=c(1,9),nlevels=9,col=shades(9))) +     
layer(xyplot(line~time,type="l"))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would go trying using `par(new=TRUE)` before drawing the second plot, but I do not use `lattice` so I do not know if it's gonna work for you.

Comment: The function filled.contour is actually not part of the lattice or latticeExtra packages. It is part of base R's graphics. It does not work together with the xyplot or layer functions which are part of lattice and latticeExtra.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the help page for `filled.contour`, you may read under "Note": *If you want to annotate the main contour plot, for example to add points, you can specify graphics commands in the plot.axes argument.*

```
### your code
require("lattice")
require("latticeExtra")

mat = matrix(c(1:9),nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)
time = c(1:3) 
mid = c(1:3)
line = colMeans(mat)

shades = colorRampPalette(c("red", "green"))

### call to filled.contour with plot.axes{} for some line
filled.contour(mid, time, t(apply(mat, 2, rev)),
           zlim = c(1, 9), nlevels = 9, col = shades(9),
           plot.axes = { axis(1); axis(2); lines(c(1.5,2, 2.5), c(2,2.8, 2.8), col = "white") }
)
```

The code yields this plot:

[image]

You could also plot the relation between your objects `line` and `time` with the following code. Remark that I had to substract `3` from `line` to make it fit in the graph:

```
filled.contour(mid, time, t(apply(mat, 2, rev)),
               zlim = c(1, 9), nlevels = 9, col = shades(9),
               plot.axes = { axis(1); axis(2); lines(line-3, time, col = "white") }
)
```

yielding the graph below:
[image]

Please let me know whether this is what you want.